# Unable to get custom post type name with get_post_type()

Tags: wordpress

> Unable to get my custom post type name to load single-jobs.php page can some please help me where i'm doing something wrong in code or is there any permalink issue.

## Code to load single page template for jobs post type

```
function wwp_job_portal_single_page($original_template){
        //check post type to job portal single page
        $type=get_post_types(); 
        if(get_query_var( 'post_type' ) !== 'jobs'){

            return ;

        }
        elseif(is_single('jobs')){
        //check if file exit of single job page template
            if(file_exists(file_exists( get_stylesheet_directory(). '/single-jobs.php' ))){

                return get_stylesheet_directory() . '/single-jobs.php';

            }
            else{

                return plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'templates/single-jobs.php';
            }

        }
        else{
            echo "<h1>jobs page loaded</h1>";
            return plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'templates/single-jobs.php';

        }
        return $original_template;
    }
     add_action('template_include','wwp_job_portal_single_page');
```

## Custom post type registration code

```
function create_jobs_post_type(){

    // set up labels
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Job',
        'singular_name' => 'Job',
        'add_new' => 'Post New Job',
        'add_new_item' => 'Post New Job',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Job',
        'new_item' => 'New Job',
        'all_items' => 'All jobs',
        'view_item' => 'View jobs',
        'search_items' => 'Search Job',
        'not_found' =>  'No Job Found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Job found in Trash', 
        'parent_item_colon' => '',
        'menu_name' => 'Jobs',
    );
    //register post type
    register_post_type( 'jobs', array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'public' => true,
        'supports' => array('title','thumbnail'),
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => 10,
        'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-id-alt',
        'can_export'          => true,
        'delete_with_user'    => false,
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'query_var'           => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'post',
        'map_meta_cap'        => true,
        // 'capabilities' => array(),

        'rewrite'             => array( 
            'slug'          => 'jobs',
            'with_front'    => true,
            'pages'         => true,
            'feeds'         => false,

        ),
        )
    );
    $taxonomy_args = array( 
      'labels'                    => array( 'name' => 'Job Category' ),
      'show_ui'                   => true,
      'hierarchical'              => true,
      'rewrite' => array( 'slug'  => 'jobs' )
    );
    register_taxonomy(
        'jobs_category',
        'jobs',
        $taxonomy_args
    );
}

//hook for theme setup
add_action('init','create_jobs_post_type');
```

Comment: Word of caution, using the same `slug` for the post type and a tax could cause issues. Change it and see if you get any improvement. 

Also, how is your single-jobs.php looking. How is the archive looking for that matter. Whats the logic

Comment: Change the slug of tax but still not able to get my custom post type name load template single-{-}.php file. Let me again explain my problem that i'm facing i want to detect my custom post type to load my single-{-}.php page file in template include hook. as shown in my code. Have you look at my post registration code again can you guide me is there any thing i missed that cause this whole issue. Thank x for replying.

Answer (score 1):

The function `get_post_type()` can be use outside the loop but then require the optional argument (`$post_id`) to be set.

In your code, you'll need to set the post ID as argument.

```
function wwp_job_portal_single_page($original_template){
    global $post;
    //check post type to job portal single page
    $type=get_post_types($post->ID); 
  .....
```

Then your function will be able to find the related post ID you are looking for.

Comment: Still unable to detect my custom post type. i'm actually using this code inside template hook to load my single-{}.php file but unable to do so.

Comment: Try redirect_template instead of template_include

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the same function with the post ID, just like :

```
get_post_type( get_the_ID() )
```

Hope that will do

Comment: For who given the negative marks but dont have the guts to say why he/she has given that : https://codex.wordpress.org/it:Riferimento_funzioni/get_post_type

Comment: I didn't downvote for your answer, but I can understand this, because, get_the_ID() will not work in a function, but it will work like this if it stands in the loop (as get_post_type() without parameter).

Comment: get_the_ID() can work outside the loop too....have you tried the code I have given....please try once

Comment: can work outside the loop, of course, but $post need to be set with setup_postdata( $post ); . In a function, you will need to set it with global $post; ....

Comment: I think, if the function called under and single page get_the_ID will return the ID of that page or post.

Comment: try to get it, you will see ;-) a function can not I'm sure of that fact !

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/ read the first line

Comment: Ha ha.... I think you are quite bookish on it....have you tried <?php echo get_the_ID(); ?> before loop in single.php. Please try once on my request... your opinion might change.... I have tried it several time and it did work for me

Comment: The code stands in a function not on single.php that why i think you're wrong.

Comment: No I am not wrong because u refer me the url  
developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id and my reply on  this only. So I am quite sure about it that get_the_ID() will work outside the loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135280/discussion-between-benoti-and-tristup).

Comment: Still unable to get my custom post type, i want to detect my custom post type on template_include hook to load singe-jobs.php page.